# Matrix elements of the self-energy in the GW approximation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, greens-functions, matrix-elements, self-energy

I have been teaching myself the $GW$ approximation (or the $G_0W_0$ version of it). I am able to follow the entire derivation of Hedin's equations, etc. and the $GW$ approximation itself. However, I get confused when it comes to evaluating the matrix elements of the self-energy operator.

As a function of the real-space coordinates and frequency, the self-energy is defined as
\begin{equation}
\Sigma(r, r', \omega)
=
\frac{i}{2 \pi} \int d\omega_1 G^0(r, r', \omega + \omega_1) W^0(r, r', \omega_1).
\end{equation}
I am trying to evaluate the matrix elements of $\Sigma$ over the unperturbed mean-field states $\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}$ and $\psi_{n'\mathbf{k}}$. Assuming that $G^0$ is diagonal in this mean-field basis, the final expression for the matrix element (see, e.g., Eq. 18 in [JCTC. 2021, 17, 2, 727–741](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00704)) is given as
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{nn'}(\mathbf{k}, \omega)
=
\frac{i}{2\pi N_k} \sum_{m\mathbf{q}} \int d\omega_1
G^0_{mm} (\mathbf{k-q}, \omega + \omega_1)
\langle n \mathbf{k}, m \mathbf{k-q} | W^0 | m\mathbf{k-q},n\mathbf{k} \rangle.
\end{equation}
**Could anyone provide an explanation and derivation behind this expression?** I have some idea that because of the two-body nature of the screened Coulomb operator, one needs to introduce an implicit trace - hence, the summation over $m$-states and sampling over $\mathbf{k}$-points. But I would really appreciate it if someone could help me derive this expression more rigorously.